# Web scraping an http text file page at repeated intervals

Tags: python-3.x

I have successfully written code to web scrape an https text page

https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/goes-xray-flux-primary.txt

this page is automatically updated every 60sec.  I have used beautifulSoup4 to do so. Here are my two questions: 1)how do I call a loop to re-scrape the page every 60 seconds? 2) since there are no html tags associated with the page how can only scrape a specific line of data?

I was thinking that I might have to save the scraped page as a CVS file then use the saved page to extract the data I need.   However, I'm hoping that this can all be done without saving the page to my local machine. I was hoping that there is some python package that can do all of this for me without saving the page.

```
import bs4 as bs

import urllib

sauce = urllib.urlopen("https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/goes-xray-flux-primary.txt").read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup (sauce,'lxml')

print (soup)
```

I would like to automatically scrape the first line of data every 60 seconds Here is an example first line of data

2019 03 30  1233   58572  45180     9.94e-09    1.00e-09

The header that goes with this data is

YR MO DA  HHMM    Day     Day       Short       Long

Ultimately I would like to use PyAutoGUI to trigger a ccd imaging application to start a sequence of images when the 'Short' and or "Long" x-ray flux reaches e-04 or greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every tool has its place.
BeautifulSoup is a wonderful tool, but the `.txt` suffix on that URL is a big hint that this isn't quite the HTML input which bs4 was designed for.
Recommend you use a simpler approach for this fairly simple input.

```
from itertools import filterfalse


def is_comment(line):
    return (line.startswith(':')
            or line.startswith('#'))


lines = list(filterfalse(is_comment, sauce.split('\n')))
```

Now you can do word split on each line to convert to CSV or pandas dataframe.
Or you can just use `lines[0]` to access the first line.
For example, you might parse it out in this way:

```
yr, mo, da, hhmm, jday, sec, short, long = map(float, lines[0].split())
```